# Add prefix icon on kendo-maskedTextbox, kendo-numericTextbox and other textbox-like controls

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-ui-angular2

On a regular Kendo UI Textbox you can add **prefix** and/or **suffix icons** (*adornments*). Cf. https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/inputs/textbox/adornments/

```
<kendo-textbox>
    <ng-template kendoTextBoxPrefixTemplate>
        <kendo-icon [name]="'user'"></kendo-icon>
        <kendo-textbox-separator></kendo-textbox-separator>
    </ng-template>
</kendo-textbox>
```

Result:
[image]

But if you try this with another control, like a Masked Textbox, that prefix template seems to be ignored. **No icon is showing.**

```
<kendo-maskedtextbox mask="00-00" [value]="value">
    <ng-template kendoTextBoxPrefixTemplate>
        <kendo-icon [name]="'menu'"></kendo-icon>
    </ng-template>
</kendo-maskedtextbox>
```

Result:
[image]

Same question for these input fields:

- kendo-numerictextbox
- kendo-autocomplete
- kendo-combobox
- kendo-dropdownlist
- kendo-multiselect
- kendo-textarea (maybe)

So if you use different controls in your form then you can't really use any textbox icons as it would be very inconsistent (some inputs have icons, some not).

Anyone knows if there is a solution for this? Or do I need to submit a feature request with Telerik? (that could take months I suppose :-()

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @johey I can get you direct help from the Kendo development team if you post this on the Kendo UI for Angular forums https://www.telerik.com/forums/kendo-angular-ui (you can always come back here with the answer to update the SO community)

Comment: Hi @lance-mccarthy, thanks for your suggestion. I will post it there tomorrow.

Comment: I've added my comments to an existing post on the Telerik forum:  https://feedback.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/1489227-allow-adornments-in-numerictextbox

Comment: That's an incorrect place to ask questions or support, it's for Feature Request planning and your technical support request will usually be ignored). Please open either a Support Ticket (if you have a license) or my original link for a Forum post.

Comment: Okay, I posted another question on https://www.telerik.com/forums/maskedtextbox-lacks-some-features-of-a-regular-textbox  (under topic https://www.telerik.com/forums/kendo-angular-ui/maskedtextbox). Thanks for your advice Lance!